# How to implement partial GET requests in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, get, streaming

I'm trying to implement a controller that will accept byte range in the request header and then return a multimedia as a byte array. When returning a file, partial requests are enabled by default.

This works. Returns 206 and part of the file when byte range is mentioned. And 200(and the whole file) when byte range is not mentioned.

```
@RequestMapping("/stream/file")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> streamFile() {
    File file = new File("/path/to/local/file");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new FileSystemResource(file));
}
```

this doesn't work. It returns 200 whether or not I mention byte range in my request header.

```
@RequestMapping("/stream/byte")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> streamBytes() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("path/to/local/file");
    byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(fileContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a ResponseEntity whose status code is 206.

[Here is the HTTP Status Code for 206 in Spring Boot.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/8680fdb8bcae5486abaeb2b8b4f81e2d1f6f4c87/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.java#L96)

So do it like this.

```
@RequestMapping("/stream/byte")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> streamBytes() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("path/to/local/file");
    byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    int numBytes = /** fetch your number of bytes from the header */;
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT).body(Arrays.copyOfRange(fileContent, 0, numBytes));
}
```

Comment: But it returns the whole object. Except of 206 code I also want it to partially return the object.

Comment: What do you mean by partially return the object?

Comment: I'm specifying 0-500 bytes on my Request header. I 'd be expecting to only return a part of the file. Not the whole file.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I have fixed my solution to reflect this. Let me know if this is correct.

Comment: Required type is ResponseEntity but instead I provide BodyBuilder

Comment: Whoops, I did it backwards - try this

Comment: "Cannot resolve method status". Also, how do I retrieve the bytes from header?

Comment: Whoops again - we are returning a 206, so no need for the ok method. Try it now.

Comment: And to get the number of bytes, use this method. Beware of heartbleed like errors though! https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d3b1c4f62b5605e2b4b2aca6d18c06c70df86152/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.java#L964